# Chrome sets element visibility to hidden

Tags: html, css

In our webbapplication we have a datefield to select an end date for an invoice. When you select the end date you open a calendar dialog and choose the date you want. The calendar dialog overlaps an underlying Component. After the calendar dialog returns, the underlying component is not visible again. When I inspect the html code I can see that chrome has added the attribute `visibility` and put the value to `hidden`. Does anyone know if it is possible to force the component to stay visible?

**Html Before**:

```
<select name="selectedTransactionTypes" size="4" id="selectedTransactionTypes" multiple="multiple" class="input" style="width: 150px">
```

**Html after**:

```
<select name="selectedTransactionTypes" size="4" id="selectedTransactionTypes" multiple="multiple" class="input" style="width: 150px; visibility: hidden;">
```

Comment: is the calender running from `jquery`?

Comment: yes, remove the `visibility: hidden` from the `selector:hover` pseudo.

Or please explain more. Does it change from css or from js/jQuery?

Comment: well this is not even going to the server. The calendar is a org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ui.AbstractUITag; so I quess it is not a jquery then?